# Uncaught ReferenceError for Javascript using onchange method

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

So yesteday it was working but now it gives me error and I have no idea why..
Here is the code i'm using:

```
<select onchange="tipus(this);">

            <option value="true">Heti tevékenység</option>
            <option value="false">Idoszakos tevékenység</option>
</select>

            <div id="ifYes" style="display: block;">
            <label class="submit" for="tipus">Orák száma</label> <input type="number" name="orak" min="1" max="99" /><br />
            </div>
            <div id="ifNo" style="display: none;">
            <label class="submit" for="napok">Napok száma:</label> <input type="number" name="napok" min="1" max="99" /><br />
            <label  class="submit" for="car">Kezdeti dátum</label> <input type="date" id="datum" name="datum" /><br />
            </div>
            <script>
            function yesnoCheck(that) {
                if (that.value == "true") {
                    document.getElementById("ifNo").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = "block";

                }
                else 
                {
                    document.getElementById("ifYes").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("ifNo").style.display = "block";
                }
            }
            </script>
```

Comment: You never define `tipus`.

Comment: Szia Dávid! Mi lenne a cél, mert több hiba is van a kódban. Ha gondolod írj egy e-mail: gabor.klement@outlook.com / Hi David! What is your goal? This code contain many error... Please contact me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The working solution:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<select id="tipus">
 <option value="true">Heti tevékenység</option>
 <option value="false">Idoszakos tevékenység</option>
</select>
 
<div id="ifYes" style="display: block;">
 <label class="submit" for="tipus">Orák száma</label>
 <input type="number" name="orak" min="1" max="99" /><br />
</div>
 
<div id="ifNo" style="display: none;">
 <label class="submit" for="napok">Napok száma:</label>
 <input type="number" name="napok" min="1" max="99" /><br />
    <label  class="submit" for="car">Kezdeti dátum</label>
 <input type="date" id="datum" name="datum" /><br />
</div>
 
<script>
 
 $('#tipus').change(function(){
  var value = $('#tipus option:selected').val();
  if (value === 'true') {
   $('#ifNo').hide();
   $('#ifYes').show();
  } else if (value === 'false') {
   $('#ifNo').show();
   $('#ifYes').hide();
  }
 });
 
</script> 
 
</body>
</html>
```